# Issues with the iOS application

Tags: support, feature-request, ios-app

This is more of a request (or a complaint), than a question. The iOS application has two bothering issues:

1. It does not render MathJax in the question titles.
2. It does not permit users to offer a bounty on their question.

Is there any progress towards fixing these two issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is by design, as explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20743/147263). Not going to change.
2. Apps interact with SE servers using [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/), so they can only do things that the API supports. Kasra Rahjerdi, the mobile team lead at SE, [said  about setting bounties](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3070523#3070523):

   > it's not in the API and it's a complex action so adding it to the API will take a while. There's a chance, but low priority.